# Building a MJPG Camera

Tags: camera

I am working on a project that needs a custom camera capable of MJPG over WIFI. The project is a solar powered camera on a track the tracks objects walking past. The device should transmit the images back to the computer that controls the device so that it can process them and send instructions back to the device.

Unfortunately due to mounting/size constraints I am unable to just rip the sensor board out of a cheap security camera (trust me, I would if I could!). This leaves me with building my own.

I started the design phase, however I can not seem to find the parts that I need, or what those parts may be called.

From my limited understanding (note that I have no experience with image processing) The block diagram should look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQBCj7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My questions are as follows:

1. What should I search for when searching for a camera sensor? I was able to turn up the OVM7690, however, that was the only sensor for under $50, which tells me I am definitely searching the wrong thing. -- ("image sensors" on digikey/mouser)
2. What do I use to process the raw RGB data into a JPEG, and is there any in between steps? What is a device like this called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright so building a camera system from scratch like this is not an easy task.  Just looking at your diagram you're missing the whole image processing section between the raw output of the sensor.   A PIC32 seems pretty under powered for this but hey you could prove me wrong.

Take a look at something like this chip from [Nuvoton](http://www.nuvoton.com/hq/products/microprocessors/arm9-mpus/n3290-mjpeg-series/?__locale=en) if you really want to do it from scratch.

I'd ask though (in a nice way) if you can't use the board from a cheap security camera what makes you think you can make a smaller version?  The size and components required will be similar.

Given the amount of effort required to make a camera from scratch, and the fact that building a camera isn't your actual goal, it might be worth it to consider other options.

Comment: Another option to consider could be the rasberry PI camera http://www.raspberrypi.org/help/camera-module-setup/  At least all the work is done for you.  You'd just have to see if you can get it in a small enough space.

Comment: Its not that it has to be smaller, it is more about the mounting constraints. The board has to be slot mounted onto the chassis, and conform to a specific size. Due to components overhead the right side of the board must be low profile, then there is about an inch and a half square where components can be unlmited size, then another low profile section, then the end of the component. It is wonderful when people follow exactly what you say, without any thought as to what you mean.

Comment: I will take a look into the nuvoton. Any clue what other processors like that would be called in general? It seems that they dont sell those in the US.

Comment: I don't know a generic name we just call them camera chips :). If you google mjpeg chip or mjpeg soc you'll get a bunch more.  My guess is most  solutions will not be us based although Freescale or TI may still have something.  The overseas guys have been crashing the prices on these low end camera chips so not much room to compete.   You may find its difficult to get any attention or support at low volume.  Heres a to reference design http://www.ti.com/tool/DM385-AR0331

Comment: Ah, Thanks didnt realize that they are actually called mjpeg chips.